# Optional date parameter in PostgreSQL query from Java not working

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

We are migrating some services from Oracle to PostgreSQL and we have our custom database access layer, based on JDBC. Almost all of our use cases are working, but our queries with optional parameters (`where field = :parameter or :parameter is null`) are not.

The original query in Oracle was:

```sql
select field
from table
where (reference = ?)
  and (date >= ? or ? is null)
```

And it worked, we tested in MySQL and it worked too. However, with PostgreSQL we get the following error:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $3`

We're testing directly with the JDBC PostgreSQL library:

```java
private static void testQuery() {
   try {
      String ref = "dummy";
      String sql = "select field From table where (reference = ?)";
      sql += " and (date >= ? or ? is null) ";
      PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, ref);
      ps.setNull(2, Types.NULL);
      ps.setNull(3, Types.NULL);
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
      while (rs.next()) {
         System.out.print("Column 1 returned: ");
         System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
      }
      rs.close();
      ps.close();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

We did test with the `coalesce` function and it worked, but the idea was to have pure SQL queries that could work in any database.

We are using PostgreSQL 12.4 and the dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

We could get it working specifying

```java
ps.setNull(2, Types.NULL);
ps.setNull(3, Types.VARCHAR);
```

It seems that it's mandatory to have the `VARCHAR` type specified when comparing a parameter to `null`.
This doesn't help us a lot since it's the same parameter from the query perspective, so we can't put two types depending on if the condition `is null` is used in our database access layer.

Until now, whenever a parameter was null, we were using `VARCHAR` as default for the Oracle and MySQL access, but then PostgreSQL gives the following error for the second parameter (date):

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= character varying`

Any ideas?

Edit: if I'm not mistaken and haven't misread [this thread](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2358767), there's not really a solution besides the (ugly in my opinion) option to specify the type of the nullable parameter in the query: `select * from my_table where ?::timestamp`.
It seems that [even JPA has the same problem](https://blog.mimacom.com/java-8-dates-with-postgresql/) and has to do the type casting.

Comment: *"testing directly with the JDBC **PostgreSQL** library ... And it **worked**"*, then *"with **PostgreSQL** we get the following **error**"*, so which is it? Is it working or not?

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry. Edited for better understanding.

Comment: Change `Types.NULL` to `Types.TIMESTAMP`. There is a *reason* you're supposed to give a type on the `setNull()` call, because you need to tell the driver what the column data type is, and `Types.NULL` is not a real data type. Sure, some JDBC drivers don't need it, but some do, and I guess PostgreSQL's JDBC driver is one of them.

Comment: Alternatively, use `setTimestamp(2, null)` and `setTimestamp(3, null)`, which is what you'd normally do anyway, because you's actually use `setTimestamp(2, dateVal)` and `setTimestamp(3, dateVal)`, where `dateVal` can optionally be `null`. --- *FYI:* `setNull()` is generally only used for setting null values for *primitive* Java data types, e.g. `int` since you can't use `setInt()` to set a null value. In short, you're using `setNull()` wrong.

Comment: It's clear, but where did I in any way say to do something different for parameter 2 vs 3? I said to change `Types.NULL` to `Types.TIMESTAMP`. That would be for both of them. I said to alternatively use `setTimestamp(?, null)`. That would be for both of them. I never said anything about setting parameter 3 in a different way from setting parameter 2.

Comment: With setTimestamp(?, null) the error is the same: `could not determine data type of parameter $3`

Comment: In the second comment I did not say to do thing different between parameters 2 and 3.

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood, it was to clarify and I deleted my comment.

Comment: Try `setDate` rather than `setNull`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) pointed out in his second comment, the problem is that the JDBC implementation of PostgreSQL is more "refined" than others and wants to know explicitly which type is the parameter, even if the value passed is `null`. This is not the case of other implementations like Oracle or MySQL, they're both happy with `Varchar` as a default type when the value is `null`.

We had no other option than to change all our queries to use `COALESCE` instead.

[Here's an old thread](https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Bug-Cannot-pass-null-in-Parameter-in-Query-for-ISNULL-td5034727.html) explaining the problem if anyone is interested, and [a more recent discussion](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2358767).

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little late but for someone who might run into this issue. I've had this problem in the past where I needed to convert the date (Java Date) to string and then back to Date, it never worked when converted back no matter what formatting I used. Until I used the Calendar.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1999)
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 12)
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime())
```

After doing what I had to do with the converted to string date, I converted it to integers and passed it to the calendar as above, you get the drill. P.S. I wish I could cite the source where I found this. If someone does, please share the link here and I'll make sure to cite.